# Enemy Teleporting Around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've already posted a lot of questions about this project, but I've run into another problem. I created a gameObject that wanders around like it should, however it teleports to the new location instead of slowly sliding over there like it should.

This is the code for moving:

```
if(directionGenerator == 1){ //up
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, totalWalkDistanceUp) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: up");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 2){ //down
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, totalWalkDistanceDown) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: down");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 3){ //left
            enemy.transform.Translate (new Vector2(totalWalkDistanceLeft, 0) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: left");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 4){ //right
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(totalWalkDistanceRight,0) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: right");
        }
```

This is the entire code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Start(){
        findPosition();
    }
    private void walkRepeat(){
        InvokeRepeating("enemyWalk", 3, 5f);
        //enemyWalk();
    }


    //Variables
    public Transform enemy;

    private Vector2 position;

    /* not necessary
    private float maxPosX;
    private float maxPosY;
    private float maxNegX;
    private float maxNegY;
    */

    public float wanderSpeed = 3;

    private float totalWalkDistanceUp;
    private float totalWalkDistanceDown;
    private float totalWalkDistanceLeft;
    private float totalWalkDistanceRight;




    private void findPosition(){
        position.x = enemy.position.x;
        position.y = enemy.position.y;

        /* not neccessary
        maxPosX = position.x + 5;
        maxNegX = position.x - 5;
        maxPosY = position.y + 5;
        maxNegY = position.y -5;
        */

        Debug.Log ("Enemy position: " + position);
        //Debug.Log ("Max positive 'x' position: " + maxPosX + ". Max positive 'y' position: " + maxPosY + ". Max negative 'x' position: " + maxNegX + ". Max negative 'y' position: " + maxNegY);
        Debug.Log ("Finished!");

        walkRepeat();
    }

    private void enemyWalk(){
        //Distance Generator
        float walkDistance = Random.Range (40f, 70f);
        totalWalkDistanceUp = walkDistance + position.y;
        totalWalkDistanceDown = position.y - walkDistance;
        totalWalkDistanceRight = walkDistance + position.x;
        totalWalkDistanceLeft = position.x - walkDistance;
        Debug.Log ("Distance generated up: " + totalWalkDistanceUp + ". Distance generated down: " + totalWalkDistanceDown + ". Distance generated left: " + totalWalkDistanceLeft + ". Distance generated right: " + totalWalkDistanceRight);

        //Direction generator
        int directionGenerator = Random.Range (1, 4);

        if(directionGenerator == 1){ //up
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, totalWalkDistanceUp) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: up");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 2){ //down
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, totalWalkDistanceDown) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: down");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 3){ //left
            enemy.transform.Translate (new Vector2(totalWalkDistanceLeft, 0) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: left");
        }
        else if(directionGenerator == 4){ //right
            enemy.transform.Translate(new Vector2(totalWalkDistanceRight,0) * wanderSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log ("Direction generated: right");
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it keeps teleporting to the new location and not sliding. I'm sure it's something simple, but thank you for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

InvokeRepeating isn't really suitable for this. That's why it looks like teleporting...
 
If you want to update its position, you should use `Update()` or if you need psychics-based movement, then you need to use `FixedUpdate()`... You probably could get around with your current approach and using `Lerp` to interpolate between values, but it would get weird real fast in my opinion...

Comment: `FixedUpdate()` works, but it makes the character move around extremely fast, is there any way to slow down `FixedUpdate()` so the character doesn't freak out?

Comment: No, FixedUpdate is happening in a fixed interval (hence the name). Tweak your variables (especially wanderSpeed).

Comment: I figured out that you can slow it down (Edit --> Project Settings --> Time then decrease the time of Fixed Timestep), but when I slowed it down I saw that the character was still teleporting instead of sliding.

Comment: Maybe you've increased deltaTime to the point that the whole move happens in one update. Did you try what walther said? You don't need to fiddle with time. If something's moving too fast... lower its speed.